# PNG file conversion to PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, png, adobe-acrobat, file-conversion

Why does an Adobe Illustrator document saved as a PNG that are then converted to PDF files look blurry and pixelated?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I don't believe that may be necessary, as I've discovered it is not workable for a PNG to be converted to a PDF. Thanks for your question.

Comment: You just asked this same exact question yesterday and I thought I laid it out pretty simply [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61185/png-file-for-pdf), when I told you NOT to save as a PNG and then as a PDF...SAVE DIRECTLY TO PDF!

Answer (score 3):

The image looks pixelated because the vector artwork is being rasterized. Edges that don't fall on whole pixels are anti-aliased.

Unless there is a specific reason to save as PNG, and I can't imagine what that would be, you should save directly to PDF to retain the vector information. Beyond having a sharper image, vector art usually produces smaller file sizes.

Comment: I experimented with settings when saving an Adobe Illustrator file as a PDF, and the results were satisfying: smaller file size and quality image. Thanks!